# Could not build Objective-C module 'Your Framework'

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, replaykit

I am using broadcast extension to capture my iPhone screen, In same project I am using some framework, which are working perfect in my project target, If same Framework I am importing in **BroadCast Extension target** like in side "SampleHandler" class(This is broadcast extension "RPBroadcastSampleHandler" Class), I am facing compiler issue as **"Could not build Objective-C module 'your framework name'"**, As framework build in objective-c and my project is in swift. I am using "POD" to install all framework. I have also try with killing Xcode, Clean drive data, uninstall POD and install back several time, But still not getting any luck. I have also try creating **Bridging-Header** and import these library in side **Bridging-Header** and getting **"Could not build module 'Your framework name'"**

Kindly suggest which changes need to do in framework code to compile in different target in same project. As we are only writing that framework.

Comment: Hi kindly suggest on my above issue. Still its not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

to make this work
Go to traget -> setting-> Require Only App-Extension-Safe API = NO

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Xcode12.5, Apple requires that all Extension targets must be set APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY to true, "Application extensions and any libraries they link to must be built with the APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY build setting set to YES "; However, we often share code between the main project and the extension using Framework or other means that use a non-extension-only API, which causes problems

To solve this problem, use the following code in the podfile:

```
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
  end
```